# Ensemble technique for combining predictions from classification and regression algorithms

Tags: classification, regression, anomaly-detection, ensemble-learning

Given an anomaly detection problem - `A`, I have divided the problem into two independent subtasks -`A1` and `A2` and tackled the tasks using classification and regression algorithms respectively. In order to combine the predictions from the classification and regression algorithms, I have derived an average weighing formula. My question is if this approach can be regarded as `ensemble learning`? Otherwise, are there better ways to combine such predictions into a common `score`? I am new here :)

**UPDATE**
Subtasks A1 and A2 are tackled with One Class SVM (unsupervised) and Gaussian  Process Regression (GPR)(supervised) respectively. The scores from both algorithms are added using weighed mean like so:

```
Final_Score = alpha * OCSVM_Score + (1 - alpha) * GPR_Score
```

where alpha = 0.5

Comment: can you add a bit more details :-) e.g. is this supervised? what's the output of your regression? and how do you average the results?

Comment: @oW_ i have updated the question with the information you requested, does it make more sense ?